# Socket.IO TypeError: Cannot read property 'broadcast' of undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, laravel, socket.io

I'm using redis with socket.io:

```
var io      = require('socket.io')(6001);
var Redis   = require('ioredis'),
var redis   = new Redis();

redis.psubscribe('*');

redis.on('pmessage', function (pattern, channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.sockets.connected[message.data.senderID].broadcast.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
```

I receive this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'broadcast' of undefined
>      at Redis. (C:\socket\htdocs\project\server.js:12:46)
>      at emitThree (events.js:135:13)
>      at Redis.emit (events.js:216:7)
>      at Redis.exports.returnReply 
>      ...

What's wrong? `console.log(message.data.senderID);` prints socket ok. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please check your socket.io version. `io.sockets.connected[socketid]` just supported in socket.io 1.x.x.

There are more ways to get a reference. Just look at the console.log(io).

In 2.x You can use `io.sockets.sockets[senserID].broadcast.emit`. //send to everyone except sender
[Refs this one](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1618)

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3 ( looks like latest ). I'm sending socket from laravel, not js. `\Event::fire(new NewTopicCreated( $_COOKIE['io'] ));` So I want to send socket for everyone from this socket ( $_COOKIE['io'] ). Any ways? Thank you !

Comment: You can try this one. `io.to(message.data.senderID).emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message)`

Comment: just `io.emit` works, but it sends to sender. io.to is not working.. any errors, but not sending. Should I move to 1.x.x version? I need something like io.from(..).to everyone except sender.

Comment: @DisplayName: try this one `io.sockets.sockets[ID].broadcast.emit`. it works for me

Comment: What version are you using? `TypeError: Cannot read property 'broadcast' of undefined` anyway :(

Comment: "socket.io": "^2.0.3"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157186/discussion-between-displayname-and-le-dinh-dam).